# how to activate MDI Child form from MDI Parrent without loop

Tags: c, winforms

Hi i am looking to open a form from MDI Parent.

if For is Already Open then it should be activated or Open New form..
Now I am using `foreach` Loop. but i don't want to use loops.

```
foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
                {
                    if (frm is FrmPrd)
                    {
                            frm.Activate();
                            frm.BringToFront();

                    }    
                        else
                        {
                            FrmPrd _OFrmPrd = new FrmPrd();
                            _OFrmPrd.Show();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

plz. suggest me how use it without loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Linq to hide loops:

```
    var form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<FrmPrd>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (form == null) new FrmPrd().Show();
    else {
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        form.Activate();
    }
```

Or just don't lose track of the instance so you don't have to loop at all, the superior solution since it also avoids a bug in Application.OpenForms:

```
    FrmPrd productForm;

    private void ShowProductButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (productForm == null) {
            productForm = new FrmPrd();
            productForm.FormClosed += (s,ea) => productForm = null;
            productForm.Show();
        }
        else {
            productForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            productForm.Activate();
        }
    }
```